# Passive construction of a sentence that starts with "no sooner"

Tags: passive-voice, clauses, negative-inversion

- We had no sooner started the work than he closed the door.
- The work had no sooner been started than he closed the door.
- The work had no sooner been started, when he closed the door.

The last two sentences are the passive constructions of first one, though I don't think that the meanings of last two are same. Please say what you think. Which one from last two is more common?

If I write the following sentence, is the meaning of it same to the first active construction?

- No sooner had we started the work than he closed the door.

Comment: *than* makes no sense there but *when* does.

Comment: @ustanak actually, it is the convention to use 'than' with 'no sooner'. Using 'when' would just be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

'No sooner' is always paired with 'than'. Using 'when' in the third sentence makes it wrong. The other sentence all mean just about the same thing. However, some are a little awkwardly written. When using 'no sooner', it's best to start the sentence with it: 'No sooner had ... than ...'. For that reason, the last sentence is probably the best of the lot.